# How to verify custom attributes in devise : Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

Well I am new to Devise authentication. Basically what I want to implement is **:**

I have two models *Residents* and *Users*.
Both *resident* and *user* model contains attribute **roll_number** !
Now we  already  have  list of roll numbers in resident model, And what I want is when user comes for registration he needs to add his roll_number,email and password if roll_number is contained in resident model then New user is created else flash message must be shown that roll_number doesn't exist.

> ((((((((***Using Devise***))))))))))

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. So generally what happens here is that we expect you to have had a go yourself. Then to show us the code you tried (even if it isn't working), the error message you got and what you expected instead... and then we can begin to help you debug your code. So... go have a bash at it - it doesn't matter if you get it wrong... just give it a shot... then come back to us when you hit a specific snag and we can help you out :)

Comment: ok :) 
but follow this question . @TarynEast

Comment: there is no follow :( if you reply to one of my comments, though, I'll see it...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38634913/custom-devise-controller-not-working       I have posted new question on this thing can u see it @TarynEast

Answer (score 0):

Only you need to override devise registration controller

```
# app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    super
  end

  def create
    # add custom create logic here
  end

  def update
    super
  end
end
```

And then tell devise to use that controller instead of the default with:

```
# app/config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}
```

Hope this will help

Comment: can we use controller's create method ?

Comment: No, If you want custom create functionality. Need to override devise create functionality.

Comment: I have posted new question on this topic can you see it , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38634913/custom-devise-controller-not-working