# Custom devise controller not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

I have two models resident and user. Both of them contains roll_number attribute, I have entered data already in resident model now I want, when user register which is an Devise resource it checks if resident is there of same roll_number in resident model? And then user can be registered !! So Basically I added attribute (roll_number) to Devise's User model, then I edited the Create method of Registrations controller here's the code of it :

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
 before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
 before_action :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]

  # GET /resource/sign_up
  # def new
  #   super
  # end

  def create
    super
    resident = Resident.find_by(roll_number: params[:roll_number])
    if resident.present?
      @user = resident.create_user(params)
      if @user.save
        flash[:info] = "Welcome to messpay"
        redirect_to root_url
      else
        render 'new'
      end
    else
      flash[:danger] = "You have entered a worng Roll number or you are not a Resident"
      redirect_to new_user_registration
    end

  end

  # GET /resource/edit
  # def edit
  #   super
  # end

  # PUT /resource
  # def update
  #   super
  # end

  # DELETE /resource
  # def destroy
  #   super
  # end

  # GET /resource/cancel
  # Forces the session data which is usually expired after sign
  # in to be expired now. This is useful if the user wants to
  # cancel oauth signing in/up in the middle of the process,
  # removing all OAuth session data.
  # def cancel
  #   super
  # end

  # protected


   def configure_sign_up_params
     devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:roll_number,:resident_id])
   end

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
   def configure_account_update_params
     devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:roll_number,:resident_id])
   end

  # The path used after sign up.
  # def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  #   super(resource)
  # end

  # The path used after sign up for inactive accounts.
  # def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  #   super(resource)
  # end
end
```

But this code isn't working and I am getting this when I am feeling the form:
[image]

here's my form code:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sign up for a free messpay account') %>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-2" style="margin-top: 10%">
    <%= image_tag("signup.jpg", alt: "Thapar",width:"475",height: "331",class:"img-responsive") %>

  </div >
  <div class="col-xs-5" id="signup_form" style="margin-top: 10%">
    <%= image_tag("messpay.gif", alt: "Messpay",height: "38",width: "120") %>

    <p style="font-size:30px;font-weight:100;"> Create an account </p>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>
        <p style="font-size: 0.87em">Messpay account <%= link_to "What's this?","#" %></p>
  <%= f.text_field :roll_number, class:'form-control',placeholder:"Roll number" %>

  <%= f.email_field :email, class:'form-control',placeholder:"Email" %>

  <%= f.password_field :password, class:'form-control',placeholder:"Password"%>

  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control',placeholder:"Password confirmation"%>

  <%= f.submit "Create account", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
  <p style="margin-top: 10%;color: gray;">Already have Messpay account<span onclick="openNav()"style="color:#0c90db;cursor:pointer;"> Login here !!</span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Am I using Params Properly ? I can't understand eaxctly why this is happening !

Comment: Your params pare probably scoped. Try `params[:user][:roll_number]`

Comment: Where? at create method ?       `@user = resident.create_user(params)` , this line ?

Comment: You need to change the routes file as well to actually run your code here.

Comment: What routes ? @Bharatsoni

Comment: devise_for :users, :controllers => {registrations: "users/registrations" }

Comment: it is saying Resident must exist in errors, but resident is present of same roll_number which I am entering @Bharatsoni , I guess controller is working

Comment: I m getting  : `reisdent doesn't exist`  but resident is present at model, I think something is worng with create_user?

Comment: Can you show us the code for the form? you might just have incorrectly labelled the form-field for the roll_number field (or is this dynamically generated... I'm not sure). Also - yeah try `params[:user][:roll_number]` and see if it fixes it... :D

Comment: You're also getting "roll number can't be blank"... which I think is the real error. I suspect that when you fix that part, it'll then find your resident.

Comment: I have added form code . , I m using params[:user][:roll_number], but not working... 
previously i were getting two errors, as in image, now just one that resident doesn't exit ! @TarynEast

Comment: Ok, so what jumps out as me is that if the code you've shown actually can't find the resident, you'd get `"You have entered a worng Roll number or you are not a Resident"` but instead you're getting an error message that is not in any of the code you've thus far included... so where is that `resident must exist` error coming from? Do you have a validation in your Resident/User models? if so, can you show us that? (it might be on `:resident` when it needs to be on `:resident_id` for instance)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put below code in `appliction_controller.rb`

```
before_action(:configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?)


def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << [:roll_number,:resident_id]]
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << [:roll_number,:resident_id]]
end
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: nope, the problem remains !, getting form error that, resident doesn't exist !

Comment: I have done that thing in registration controller !!